# "cd : permission denied" though group has access

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

Hope the following explains it. apps folder belongs to devgrp with rwx group access and jenkins user belongs to devgrp. however I am not able to cd into the folder as jenkins.

P.S: I have logged out and logged back in after adding users to the group.

```
jenkins@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/bitnami$ ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bitnami devgrp   17 Apr 17 10:55 apps -> /opt/bitnami/apps
-r-------- 1 bitnami bitnami 419 May 29 04:47 bitnami_credentials
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bitnami bitnami   0 May 31 04:08 do.deploy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bitnami bitnami  27 Apr 17 10:55 htdocs -> /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bitnami bitnami  12 Apr 17 10:55 stack -> /opt/bitnami
jenkins@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/bitnami$ cd apps
bash: cd: apps: Permission denied
jenkins@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/bitnami$ groups
jenkins sudo devgrp
jenkins@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/bitnami$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-xx-xx-xx 4.4.0-1060-aws #69-Ubuntu SMP Sun May 20 13:42:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
jenkins@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:/home/bitnami$
```

Comment: The problem is that `apps` is a symbolic link to another directory. You need to check the permissions to that directory.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on /opt and /opt/bitnami . Oops, sorry dude

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just figured that out, thanks though :) New to linux and wasn't aware of symbolic links.

Comment: @Cyrus oh sorry, is there a way to move it to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. I'd like to leave this question for people having the same problem.

Comment: I asked the moderators about this. Maybe it'll be done.

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld /opt /opt/bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps` to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your `/home/bitnami/apps` file is a symbolic link to `/opt/bitnami/apps`.

When you check permission on that kind of file, you will always have something like "lrwxrwxrwx" that is **l**ink, (**r**ead, **w**rite, e**x**ecute)*3.

---

**Your permissions are in another castle!**

In fact, the real permissions are stored elsewhere, and you can check them using `ls -l /opt/bitnami/apps`.

Remember that folders need both execution and read permissions in order to allow users to enter in and see which files are there.

You can solve your problem with `chmod 770 /opt/bitnami/apps`.

---

**Inheritance**

Furthermore, if you need that all files and subdirectories of that folder have to be assigned to the group `devgrp`, you can use `chmod 4770 /opt/bitnami/apps`.

That will set group inheritance on and every new created file (or folder) will be assigned to the same group as the parent directory (`devgrp` in this specific case).