# group symlink access denied

Tags: permissions, symlink, group

I have a symlinked directory that I cannot access. The other user has created a folder in their home directory and created a symlink to it in a place I can access, but I get 'permission denied'. I have followed the accepted answer to this question ["cd : permission denied" though group has access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447162/cd-permission-denied-though-group-has-access) but still get permission denied.

The real directory gives (according to the owner)

```
drwsrwx--- 2 ckeatch oz250     33K Jun  8 16:25 PAC


ls -lh /home/ckeatch/PAC*
total 107K
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ckeatch oz250 1.4K May 13 12:19 comod_practice.py
```

I am a member of oz250 group, and the sym link gives me

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ckeatch oz250 17 Jun  8 16:23 /fred/oz250/scripts/PAC -> /home/ckeatch/PAC

$ cd /fred/oz250/scripts/PAC/
-bash: cd: /fred/oz250/scripts/PAC/: Permission denied
$ ls -lh /fred/oz250/scripts/PAC/comod_practice.py
ls: cannot access /fred/oz250/scripts/PAC/comod_practice.py: Permission denied
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Logged into your own account, can you post the output of the **id** command ?

Comment: do you have both read and execute permission on /home/ckeatch as well as /home/ckeatch/PAC?

Comment: @cas No, I don't - the idea is to have access to just the PAC directory, not their whole home space. Is this the problem?

Comment: @MC68020 uid=11028(will) gid=503(work) groups=503(work),10191(work_users),10350(oz120),10417(oz158),10434(oz250),10453(oz256),10480(oz259),10495(oz261)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You need read and execute permission to every parent directory of PAC, all the way back to `/`. If you need access to PAC but ckeatch doesn't want you to have access to their home dir too, the only option is for PAC to be moved out of ~ckeatch to somewhere you both have access to (and can both symlink into your own home dirs). e.g. /home/PAC or /home/oz250/PAC or similar. Moving the PAC directory will, of course, require root privs. BTW, the PAC dir should be `rwx` to user & group AND **setgid** so all files created in it are in group oz250. e.g. chmod 2775 or 2770.

Comment: @cas Thanks for the explanation, makes sense. Unfortunately, only home spaces get backed up on this system, shared spaces don't. I guess we will have to look at using a code repository of some kind instead.

Comment: @cas, want to post that as an answer?

Comment: no, but if that worked for you then write it up as an answer, a summary of what you did and a brief explanation will do. i'll probably upvote it when i see it, and you can accept your own answer in a few days if nobody posts an answer you like better.